# Evaluating and graphing functions in MATLAB

Tags: graphics, matlab

I am trying to graph the following Gaussian function in MATLAB (should graph in 3 dimensions) but I am making some mistakes somewhere. What is wrong?

```
sigma = 1
for i = 1:20
    for j = 1:20
        z(i,j) = (1/(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-(i^2+j^2)/(2*sigma^2));
    end
end
surf(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are likely having is that you are evaluating the Gaussian over the range of 1 to 20 for both `i` and `j`. Since `sigma` is 1, you are only going to see a segment of one side of the Gaussian (not including the center at `[i,j] = [0,0]`), and the values of `z` from 3 to 20 in each direction are very close to 0.

Instead of using for loops, you can do things "the MATLAB way" by creating matrices of `x` and `y` values using the function [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) and performing [element-wise operations](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) on them to compute and plot `z`:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-4:0.1:4);  %# Use values from -4 to 4 in x and y directions
z = (1/(2*pi*sigma^2)).*exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)./(2*sigma^2));  %# Compute z
surf(x,y,z);  %# Plot z
```